# Battery Life on Desire HD

Tags: battery-life, htc-desire-hd

Why does the battery for android phones perform much better after 2 or 3 weeks of usage? Is there any logical reason?

Comment: Is your question about the battery in the Desire or in Android devices in general?

Comment: I didn't notice a significant difference in battery life after a little usage, except insofar as after two or three weeks I wasn't playing with my new "toy" as much and just using it.

Comment: My question is about Android phones in general and DHD specifically, I heard that Android manages the phone usage after a while and saves more battery power. I don't have a logical reason till now.

Comment: I've had the Desire HD for 2 weeks with the following settings
- auto contrast
- GPS + wifi + bluetooth off
- background data on, with services retrieving data once a day

i get around 5 hours of usage out of the stock 1250mAh battery.

I need to charge 2 full batteries to go thru my day, with short charging at work when the first battery dies out.

Answer (score 2):

I'll agree with Al Everett and say that the amount of playing with the new toy is certainly a factor early on.

I also did not notice any intrinsic changes in the systems battery management over time.  I did however notice a massive increase in battery life by turning off auto-sync, and even mobile on occasion.  With those two on, I'd see a significant drop in battery when I slept overnight, but it doesn't budge with those two off.

I use two power control widgets, the HTC data dashboard and the Android power control widget. Between the two, it's a piece of cake to tweak power settings to make sure I get the most out of the battery.

Answer (score 1):

It does not.  If you don't change any settings, Android will always do power management the same way.  Installing and removing apps can affect battery life since running processes may eat battery while your acreen is locked, and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Actually battery life can change and according to [this post from HTC](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=712990) it can even be improved by the steps outlined in the post.